# Facebook Graph API php cURL request returns partial data for AdCreative, despite sufficent permission (no error given)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am working on a PHP-based web app that's to be used internally by my agency's 3 team members, to read campaign and ads data.
Ideally, for the sake of security, the tool would never have the ability to edit ads.
It's a comparatively simple tool, I think. So I opted for cURL requests rather than using the PHP Business SDK.

The App is in 'In Development' mode, and it's being access by a System User in Business Manager whose token permissions are:

- read_insights
- ads_read
- pages_read_engagement

The System User has been given access to the following Assets:

```
The Ad Account. Permissions granted: View Performance
The Page. Permissions granted: View Page Performance
```

With those settings in place, the application is able to pull almost everything needed to view the info we require for our campaigns/ad sets/ads. I'm quite proud of it. But there's only one problem. I can't seem to get the destination URL for any ads through any API requests.

From what I understand, I need to query an ad's AdCreative.

With php cURL requests like this:

```
$access_token = "REDACTED";
$app_secret = "REDACTED";
$appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, $app_secret);
$handle = curl_init();

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/23845023771530707?fields=object_story_spec,thumbnail_url,link_url,call_to_action_type&access_token=$access_token&appsecret_proof=$appsecret_proof";


curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

$result = json_decode($output,true);
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";
```

I get the following return:

```
Array
(
    [object_story_spec] => Array
        (
            [page_id] => 104422504276761
        )

    [thumbnail_url] => https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCP_C2YI....Shortened here for clarity of this post
    [id] => 23845023771530707
)
```

In short, only about half of the fields seem to populate. I really need to get the final destination URL of an ad. I do not get the link_url or call_to_action_type fields that I requested. :(

So, I'm wondering things like...

1. Am I going about this wrong? Is AdCreative the wrong way to query this info?
2. Am I somehow still lacking permissions?
3. Am I unable to get these fields because the App in still 'In Development'? Do I need to submit the App for Review?

Sorry there are several questions here rolled into one post.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am getting the same issue whether on the graph api explorer as well as the node JS fb library

Comment: You have no idea how happy I am to hear from you @DavidJones. But only because misery loves company, I'm afraid. I still have not figured this one out. If I find a solution outside of stackoverflow, I promise I'll post it here. Good luck to us both!

Comment: As crushing as it was to hear that you hadn't had any luck, your post made my day. 
Fortunately, I believe I have the solution. The field `object_story_spec` is used to "create a new unpublished page post" and has a value of null if the ad is created with an existing page post. According to the docs, the field `effective_object_story_id` is a guaranteed reference to the object that is stored with `object_story_spec` content. So if you hit /{effective_object_story_id}?fields=call_to_action etc you should get what you need  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-post/

Comment: Wow @DavidJones, thanks. That's tremendously helpful. It's getting me the required info for links, which is wonderful. Can you make this an official answer, so I can check it, and get you some stackoverflow reputation points?

Comment: That's great news @Chris. I'm very glad to hear this has helped. Users of facebook graph api needn't suffer in silence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `object_story_spec` in the creative object is only present if the ad created a new page-post on publish. It won't be present if the ad was created referencing an existing page-post.

Fortunately, the reference to the created/referenced page-post `effective_object_story_id` should exist on every ad-creative.

You can query the page-post via `/{effective_object_story_id}?fields=...` to find the data that would have otherwise existed in `object_story_spec`.

ad-creative: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative

page-post: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-post